# What is a good way to get a ordered collection from a view model for bindings with MVVM Light?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I have a view model that currently exposes an ObservableCollection. With my WP7 app, I need to show a secondary screen that basically lets you sort what comes out of the collection, and you  to the results again.

I started adding a ApplyOrder method on the view model to address this, but quickly realized I was not sure what direction to take, as when you add the orderby, you wind up with an IOrderedEnumerable.

What is the best way to get those results ordered?

Thanks,
Roger

Comment: not sure what you're trying to do - do you want to know how to pass the OC between 2 VMs or how to bind the OC to 2 different views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CollectionViewSource` is your friend.

Assign its Source property to your ObservableCollection and Add one or more SortDescriptions.